# Converting an image file to a shapefile

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile

I have [this road map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYRhN.png) in Nepal as an image within a pdf, distinguishing different types of roads by colors or line type. I am trying to make a shapefile from the image. What is the best practice converting an image to a shapefile? Ideally, I would like to work in R, where I do most geospatial analysis.

Answer (score 1):

This is the non-trivial task of vecotorizing a raster image. A popular open surce software for this task is [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). There is even a wrapper named [geotiff2shp](http://www.imagico.de/map/geotiff2shp.php) for potrace for generating Shapefiles.

Note that you might first need to seperate the different streetmaps by color. If the image uses antialiasing, you should do a color quantization before to make sure that every street type only uses a single color. Color quantization can be done, e.g. interactively in Gimp by converting the image type to "indexed".